# Correspondence between ideals of a valuation ring and value group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, order-theory

I'm reading [number theory seminar notes from Stanford](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/Perfseminar/Notes/L2.pdf). I found the following exercise, posting the abridged version:

> Let $R$ be a valuation ring with fraction field $K$. Let $\Gamma := \Gamma_R = K^{\times}/R^{\times}$ be the
> value group of $R$, and $v$ the valuation on $K$ given by reduction
> modulo $R^\times$. Consider the mapping $M_I:= I \mapsto v(I \backslash \{0\})$
>
> We leave to the reader as an exercise to prove that this is an
> inclusion-preserving bijection from the set of ideals of $R$ onto the
> set of submonoids $M \subset Γ_{\le 1}$ such that $m \in M, \gamma \le m \Rightarrow γ \in M$

This exercise has defeated me: how should I think about proving it?

Answer (score 1):

This is only the definitions, there is nothing to prove.

The word submonoid is useless, any subset $M$ of $v(R)$ satisfying $m \in M, \gamma\in v(R),\gamma \ge m \Rightarrow γ \in M$ represents the ideal $\{ a\in R,v(a)\in M\}$.

$v(R)$ is totally ordered by definition of "valuation ring", if $a,b\in R-0$ then either $a/b$ or $b/a$ is in $R$,

$v$ is the map $K^\times \to K^\times/R^\times$ extended with $v(0)=\infty$ and the order $v(b)\ge v(a)$ iff $b \in a R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand it, except the second sentence: why does any such subset (i.e. satisfying $m \in M, \gamma \le m \Rightarrow γ \in M$) represents an ideal in $R$ with valuation in $M$?

Comment: Which step exactly is unclear to you? That $\{ a\in R,v(a)\in M\}$ is an ideal?

Comment: Yes, exactly that part. Would it then be true that every valuation ring ideal is an upper set?

Comment: An upper set? If $v(b),v(c)\in M$ then wlog $v(b)\le v(c)$ so that $c=bd$ and $v(b)\le v(b(1+d)) = v(b+c)\in M$.

Comment: Yes, by definition [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set]  for all $u\in U$ and all $ x\in X,$ if $u\leq x$ then $x\in U$. Which is the property we have in terms of $m$ and $\gamma$

Comment: It is an "upper set" of the value group which is really just the group of (fractional) principal ideals $aR,a\in K^\times$. This group doesn't need being embedable in $\Bbb{R}$ (though it will be embedable in the hyperreal numbers following axiom of choice stuffs)

Comment: Ok, thank you. One last question. The note also say "we see that ideals of R give rise to submonoids of $\Gamma$ contained in $Γ_{\le 1}$ under the mapping
$I \mapsto v(I \backslash \{0\}) =: M_I$ ." Why is it $Γ_{\le 1}$ specifically, rather than just $\Gamma$?

Comment: Your $1$ means $R^\times$ the identity of the value group and you are using $\le$ instead of $\ge$ because you are not following the standard convention for "valuations". $v(R) = \{ a\in v(K),v(a)\ge v(1)\}$.